# Illegal assignment from Datetime to Date

Tags: apex, date, datetime, compile-error

I am trying to map a custom object's CreatedDate to another custom object's custom date field. But I am getting this error:

> Illegal assignment from Datetime to Date

I am doing something like this:

Assume that I assigned a variable already to `Object1__c`, and I want to map the value of its `CreatedDated` to `Date__c` field of `Object2__c`.

```
Object2__c ob2 = new Object2__c();
ob2.Date__c = ob1.CreatedDate; // error here
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get the `Date` value from a `Datetime` instance by calling the `date()` method:

```
obj2.Date__c = obj1.CreatedDate.date();
```

If you're calling this method on a `Datetime` instance where you are not sure if it can be null, make sure to add a null check:

```
obj2.Date__c = (obj1.CreatedDate == null) ? null : obj1.CreatedDate.date();
```